# Troubleshoot PHP fwrite: overwrite int for counter

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite, fread

A quick disclaimer: This is my second PHP project and the first scripting language I've worked with.

This little ditty is a gateway to implementing a counter. The thing is, it runs, but doesn't increment correctly. The file count.txt retains the initial 0 value(on the top line) and adds 1's consecutively to the second line(for each time it's run, like "1111"). The resulting echo is "Current count: 1", every time.

A few tutorials that I've seen, fopen('r') the orginal to add/echo out, then fopen('w') again to save. I've tried that, which absolutely works. I'm just exploring if it can be consolidated. Any insight into why it's skipping to the second line or suggestions in general are greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
$countfile = "count.txt";
$counthandle = fopen($countfile, "r+");
$count = intval(@fread($counthandle, filesize($countfile)));
$count++;
echo "Current count: ";
echo $count . "<br/>\n";
fwrite($counthandle, $count);
fclose($counthandle);
?>
```

Comment: Seek the file to the beginning before writing (I think with `fseek`).

Answer (score 0):

Try using [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents) and [file_put_contents](http://www.php.net/file_put_contents)

```
<?php
$countfile = 'count.txt';
$count = intval(file_get_contents($countfile));
$count++;
printf ("Current count:<br />%s", $count);
file_put_contents($countfile, $count);
?>
```